# Is there anyway to hook an event to django-cms page publish event

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm trying to hook an event during page publish event in Django CMS

Comment: You'll have to write your own signal as there isn't one for when a page is published; then hook into it.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to `models.py`:

```
from cms.signals import post_publish, post_unpublish  

post_publish.connect(self._receiver)
post_unpublish.connect(self._receiver)

def _receiver(self, sender, **kwargs):
    #logic goes here
```

Sourse: [https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/signals/**init**.py](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/signals/__init__.py)